# What is the equivalence of CSharp.Syntax.BlockSyntax in VisualBasic.Syntax API classes in Roslyn?

Tags: c#, vb.net, roslyn

We have a bunch of our own Roslyn based tools which are used to modify CS code. We wanted to extend the library with not much re-writing it to modify VB.Net code on our VB.Net based projects.

I noticed that there are more than a few basic important classes in CSharp.Syntax which do not have an equivalent in VB.Net (or at least I can't find them)

e.g:

```
CSharp.Syntax.BlockSyntax in VisualBasic.Syntax.?
```

or

```
CSharp.Syntax.VariableDeclarationSyntax in VisualBasic.Syntax.?
```

or

```
CSharp.Syntax.SyntaxFactory.ParseStatement() method in VisualBasic.Syntax.SyntaxFactory.?()
```

What are their equivalent classes in Microsoft.CodeAnalyses.VisualBasic.Syntax ??

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is no such BlockSyntax for VB.Net syntax. Each statement has it's own type.